# Animating an image with a free-transform applied?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, raphael

I am using `raphael js` and `raphael free-transform` in my web application. The problem is when I am animating Image, Only image is animating, not free-transform bbox. I want that free-trnsform bbox should move with image when I start animation. How to do it?

My code:

```
<b>Click on rectangle</b>
 <div  id="editor"></div>
```

JS:

```
var paper = Raphael("editor", 635,500),
        canvas= document.getElementById('editor').style.backgroundColor='gray';
r = paper.rect(80,40,200,80,5).click(function () {
r.animate({transform:"r-10,0,0"}, 1000); 
});

r.attr({
         fill:'red',
    });
 ft= paper.freeTransform(r,{draw:['bbox'],
            rotate: true,keepRatio:[ 'axisX', 'axisY', 'bboxCorners', 'bboxSides'],
            scale:[ 'axisX', 'axisY', 'bboxCorners', 'bboxSides' ]});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LJTPU/11/

Comment: Not sure what would happen if you put the freetransform element in a set and animated that ? Or remove/readd the freetransform during the animation each time ? Not quite ideal I know, just trying to think of alternate approaches, The freetransform doesn't work in the fiddle you've posted so is a bit hard to see the problem properly and experiment, so you may want to update that.

Comment: @Ian .. fiddle is working. Just click on rectangle to start the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the way to do it..It is working fine.

ft.attrs.rotate =ft.attrs.rotate+90;

Comment: There is an issue with this. It is rotating only once.I want to rotate in cycle.